# Decoupling Monolith Without Introducing Performance Issues

Tags: microservices, decoupling

I am currently trying to decouple a monolith into microservices and am running into performance issues. Currently, I have a ServiceX which requires a list of parameters to run, call them p1, p2, and p3. However, the last 2 parameters are data structures which are loaded from other services such as ServiceY and ServiceZ. Therefore, I have to call 2 services to gather p2 and p3 before being able to call ServiceX. In addition, ServiceY and ServiceZ may have their own dependencies from other services. My initial strategy was to instead have my ServiceX hit the DB directly in order grab the data I need for p2 and p3 internally. Therefore, my ServiceX will no longer be reliant on ServiceY and ServiceZ.

However, now, ServiceX takes a large performance hit by making these extra DB calls. In addition, I now have duplicate code to load p2 in ServiceX and ServiceY and duplicate code to load p3 in ServiceX and ServiceZ.

Is there a better pattern I should be using to get around these issues? The data provided from ServiceX, ServiceY, and ServiceZ is different and belongs in different services.

Answer (score 0):

So one of the fundamental tennets of microservices is that each individual service owns its own data completely; and your solution of reading directly from another services's data violates that premise directly. It is not what you need. Your better solution here is to introduce a caching layer between the services where the performance is a problem.

Another solution to the problem is going to be greater parallelism for the services and better optimization for the data layer (is the persistence technology being used the correct one for the problem, for example.)

It is extremely difficult to give you a reasonable answer beyond extremely generic architectural pointers; but maybe this will help.

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for the reply! Can you elaborate what you mean by "caching layer between the services"? I thought you were saying the services should not interact with one another. So why would there be a caching layer between them?

In addition, by persistence layer for the data, do you mean utilizing cache before grabbing straight from the DB?

Comment: No, what I mean is that the service A should not interact with Service B's tables/dataset- what you need is for service B to cache results for each query in either an in memory cache such as Caffeine or a distributed cache like Redis or memcached. If service B finds the result in the cache, it just returns that value -> you'll get some significant performance improvements. Caching is a vital part of any performant microservice architecture.